# For a maven dependency, how to find out which import in which Java class comes from it?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml

`my_project` has `upstream_project` as a dependency in its `pom.xml`, but I have no idea why this is necessary. How can I find out which class in `my_project` is importing from `upstream_project`, using either Maven command-line or IntelliJ?

I'm using Maven 3.3.3 and IntelliJ 14.1.

Comment: can you not simply search your project for a string containing the dependency package name? Use find in path (ctrl+shift+f )

Comment: @alan7678 OK I think that's doable. However, what if the dependency package name is so general/vague that it's prevalently used in other ways? And I'd be surprised if Maven doesn't provide this capability.

Comment: search "import (package name)" i cant think of many cases where import would show up in a string before the package name.

Comment: You can also temporarily [disable the dependency in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-maven-dependencies.html?origin=old_help). Also, you can use [the maven dependency analyzer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) to quickly sanity-check that a dependency is actually being used or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty trick:

Remove the dependency from your pom file.

Run `mvn clean install -U` and see what breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Comment-out your upstream_project dependency, and try running maven compile on command-line. If your project is missing classes from upstream_project you will get compilation errors for missing symbolic names.